# Why is my update function creating an entirely new force-directed graph?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, directed-graph

I'm looking at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539294/adding-new-nodes-to-force-directed-layout) and [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/1095795) provided in that question, and I cannot quite get my own update function to work:

```
update = function() {
    path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links());
    path.enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#666")
        .attr("stroke-width",
              function(d) {
                  return (Math.floor(Math.log(d.value - min_val) / Math.log(2)) + 1) + "px"
              })
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#generic_arrow_marker)")
        .on("mouseover",
            function(d, i) {
                if(d3.select(this).attr("stroke") != "#666") {
                    mousedOut = false;
                }
            })
        .on("mouseout",
            function(d, i) {
                if(d3.select(this).attr("stroke") != "#666") {
                    mousedOut = true;
                    restoreGraph();
                }
            });
    path.exit().remove();
    circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(force.nodes());
    circle.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r",
              function(d) {
                  return (20 + Math.floor(Math.log(d.pagerank) / Math.log(2)) * 2) + "px"
              })
        .attr("fill", "#ccc")
        .attr("stroke", "#333")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .on("mouseover", // select relevant data nodes on click
            function(d, i) {
                mousedOut = false;
                d3.select(this).attr("class", "selected");
                transitions(d);
                $("span#user").text(d.name)
                $("span#pagerank").text(d.pagerank)
            })
        .on("click",
            function(d, i) {
                incoming = !incoming;
                transitions(d);
            })
        .on("mouseout",
            function(d, i) {
                mousedOut = true;
                d3.select(this).attr("class", "");
                restoreGraph();
            })
        .call(force.drag);
    circle.exit().remove();
    text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
        .data(force.nodes());
    textEnter = text.enter().append("svg:g");
    textEnter.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    textEnter.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    text.exit().remove();
    force.start();
}
```

Whenever I call `update()`, it creates an entirely new copy of the existing D3 graph, even if I didn't change anything.

Ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as soon as I posted the question...

It was because I had `svg.append("svg:g")` for `path`, `circle`, and `text`.

I think I'll leave this question up in case it helps anyone else...